# How to use vlookup or formulas in SXSSFWorkbook with Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am Java developer. I am trying to write a large `xlsx` file (Excel) using the `SXSSFWorkbook` class of the Apache POI library.

I have no choice to write large file due have more than 200000 rows.
but I need to use some formulas or vlookup with external sheet. when I use:

```
cell.setCellFormula(formulasString);
```

But it is not working and it is returning 0 value.

**Q- How to use formulas with SXSSFWorkbook ?**

My Code -

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

public class Demo2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable 
    {
          SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk

          FormulaEvaluator fEvaluator=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

          Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();
          for(int rownum = 0; rownum < 100000; rownum++)
          {
               Row row = sh.createRow(rownum);
               for(int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum++)
               {
                  Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
                  String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
                  cell.setCellValue(address);
               }

               Cell cell1 = row.createCell(12);
               cell1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
               String sF = "SUM(10,20,30)";
               cell1.setCellFormula(sF);
               fEvaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();

               Cell cell2 = row.createCell(13);
               cell2.setCellValue("Test");
         }

         // Rows with rownum < 900 are flushed and not accessible
         for(int rownum = 0; rownum < 99900; rownum++)
         {
              Assert.assertNull(sh.getRow(rownum));
         }

         // ther last 100 rows are still in memory
         for(int rownum = 99900; rownum < 100000; rownum++)
         {
              Assert.assertNotNull(sh.getRow(rownum));
         }

         FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("sxssf.xlsx");
         wb.write(out);
         out.close();

         // dispose of temporary files backing this workbook on disk
         wb.dispose();
         System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Please, give me suggestion if possible.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a line where you use the FormulaEvaluator to evaluate the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the SXSSFWorkbook does not support formulas in version 3.12. I've found this too be true in code, however, I didn't see any official POI documentation concerning this.

The [POI documentation for formula evaluation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) has some sample code for evaluating formulas after the cell is created. It says that it works for XSSFWorkbook and HSSFWorkbook implementations but doesn't mention for the SXSSFWorkbook.

I've tried to use SXSSFWorkbook in the sample code and received an exception. Looking at the exception it clear that formula can not be evaluated by a SXSSFWorkbook despite not being explicitly stated in the POI documentation.

```
Unexpected type of cell: class org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell. Only XSSFCells can be evaluated.
```

Comment: SXSSF should be fine with formulas, are you able to write a junit test that shows your problem?

Comment: They don't work. The formula is added to the cell but the value is not calculated.

Comment: You'll need to trigger recalculation while the cell is still in memory. POI doesn't re-calculate formulas until you ask it to, see [the docs for details](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)

Comment: I appreciate the assistance but tried it and it doesn't work. In the documentation on your link it never says SXSSF will do formulas. Every line in the example code will say this:

Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis); //or new XSSFWorkbook("/somepath/test.xls")

In trying to change my working code from  XSSFWorkbook to SXSSFWorkbook and using the example code to print out the evaluated cell value I get this exception:

Unexpected type of cell: class org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell. Only XSSFCells can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, and the information given in comments, your problem is that you're using too old a version of Apache POI. That's why you're getting exceptions when you try to evaluate SXSSF cells. As [detailed towards the end of the Formula Evaluation documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#sxssf), for SXSSF formula evaluation, you need to be using 3.13 beta 2 or later.

One more potential problem - Formula Evaluation needs not only the cell with the formula in to be in memory, but also any other cells it refers to, and any they refer to. This could cause you issues, depending on how wide an area your vlookup tries to call. All cells the vlookup needs must be available in the current window, and not flushed to disk. You might therefore need to simplify your formula, and/or increase the window size, to ensure that each vlookup cell can find the values of all the cells it depends on at evaluation time

Comment: Was that SXSSF portion to the poi doc added just now? I didn't see it when I was investigating the problem. That is good that SXSSF beta versions can do formulas. I'll wait for a release candidate to come out to use it, however.

Comment: @superbAfterSemperPhi The SXSSF portion of the docs was added around the same time that the matching support was added! 3.13 beta 2 will hopefully go to a vote next week, in the mean time you could always grab a nightly build to test with

Answer (score 0):

wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

set this before doing wb.write(out)
wen u open the file i excel..excel recalculates and u get the calculated output